# Error while uploading file in web server in every 10 sec

Tags: vbscript

**The following code i used for Uploading code without loop and  code works fine while i use no loop function.**

```
dim strURL
Dim password
Dim username 
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
UploadDest= wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("https://webdav.pcloud.com/Public%20Folder/")
UploadFile = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%.txt")
 username = "abc@gmail.com"
 password = "abc"
sData = getFileBytes(UploadFile, UploadType)
Set HttpReq =createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
strURL = UploadDest & "/" & UploadFile
HttpReq.Open "PUT",strURL,False,username,password
HttpReq.send sData 
function getFileBytes(flnm,sType)
  Dim objStream
  Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  if sType="binary" then
    objStream.Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
  else
    objStream.Type = 2 ' adTypeText
    objStream.Charset ="ascii"
  end if
  objStream.Open
  objStream.LoadFromFile flnm
  if sType="binary" then
    getFileBytes=objStream.Read 'read binary'
  else
    getFileBytes= objStream.ReadText 'read ascii'
  end if
  objStream.Close
  Set objStream = Nothing
end function
```

**But when I use above code in loop i got syntax error in line no:12**

```
function getFileBytes(flnm,sType)
```

**I used following code to upload file in loop in every 10 sec .**

```
set i = 0
Do While i = 0
dim strURL
Dim password
Dim username 
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
UploadDest= wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("https://webdav.pcloud.com/Public%20Folder/")
UploadFile = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%.txt")
 username = "abc@gmail.com"
 password = "abc"
sData = getFileBytes(UploadFile, UploadType)
Set HttpReq =createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
strURL = UploadDest & "/" & UploadFile
HttpReq.Open "PUT",strURL,False,username,password
HttpReq.send sData 
function getFileBytes(flnm,sType)
  Dim objStream
  Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  if sType="binary" then
    objStream.Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
  else
    objStream.Type = 2 ' adTypeText
    objStream.Charset ="ascii"
  end if
  objStream.Open
  objStream.LoadFromFile flnm
  if sType="binary" then
    getFileBytes=objStream.Read 'read binary'
  else
    getFileBytes= objStream.ReadText 'read ascii'
  end if
  objStream.Close
  Set objStream = Nothing
end function
WScript.Sleep(10000)
loop
```

Comment: That's not JavaScript. Looks like some flavor of BASIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a `Function` inside a `Loop`

Rewrite like this to define the function outside of the loop:

```
Dim i
Do While i = 0
    dim strURL
    Dim password
    Dim username 
    Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    UploadDest= wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("https://webdav.pcloud.com/Public%20Folder/")
    UploadFile = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%.txt")
    username = "abc@gmail.com"
    password = "abc"
    sData = getFileBytes(UploadFile, UploadType)
    Set HttpReq =createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    strURL = UploadDest & "/" & UploadFile
    HttpReq.Open "PUT",strURL,False,username,password
    HttpReq.send sData 
    WScript.Sleep(10000)
loop

function getFileBytes(flnm,sType)
  Dim objStream
  Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  if sType="binary" then
    objStream.Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
  else
    objStream.Type = 2 ' adTypeText
    objStream.Charset ="ascii"
  end if
  objStream.Open
  objStream.LoadFromFile flnm
  if sType="binary" then
    getFileBytes=objStream.Read 'read binary'
  else
    getFileBytes= objStream.ReadText 'read ascii'
  end if
  objStream.Close
  Set objStream = Nothing
end function
```

Comment: Error: object required: '[number:0]'. plz correct it sir.

Comment: If you want me to fix your code for you I can send you a quote.

Comment: @ Geert Bellekens I am a student. :) so,how can i send YOU a quote.

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to debug and fix your code yourself.

Comment: @ Geert Bellekens true sir & i am keep trying it.

Comment: @ Geert Bellekens Just by removing `set i = 0` from above code ,it is working fine for me.

Comment: @ Geert Bellekens Thank you.